# Discord.py Guild.bans() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: discord, discord.py

**Code:**

```
@tree.command(name="unban",description="Unbans a member.",guild=discord.Object(id=guildid))
async def unban(ctx,member:str):
        bannedusers = await discord.Guild.bans()
        membername,memberdiscriminator = member.split("#")
        for banentry in bannedusers:
            user = banentry.user
            if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (membername, memberdiscriminator):
                await ctx.guild.unban(user)
```

**Error:**
`Guild.bans() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I tried also use discord.Guild.unban and discord.Member.unban, both give the same error

Comment: Does `member.guild.bans()` instead of `discord.Guild.bans()` work?

Comment: @dan1st  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Guild'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `discord.Guild` which is a class and thus not instantiated. Try `ctx.guild.bans()`

API Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.bans

Comment: AttributeError: module 'discord.guild' has no attribute 'bans'

Comment: My bad @ashwoda, discord.guild doesn't point to a Guild obj. I have corrected the answer, try `ctx.guild.bans()`

Comment: now I get TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: `bannedusers = [_ban async for _ban in ctx.guild.bans()]` this would make bannedusers and array of type BanEntry, you can then access the user by `bannedusers[index].user`